# Too small initial heap error - stanford parser

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am trying my hands on the Stanford dependency parser. I tried running the parser from command line on windows to extract the dependencies using this command:

```
java -mx100m -cp "stanford-parser.jar" edu.stanford.nlp.trees.EnglishGrammaticalStructure -sentFile english-onesent.txt -collapsedTree -CCprocessed -parserFile englishPCFG.ser.gz
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM  
Too small initial heap
```

I changed the memory size to -mx1024, -mx2048 as well as -mx4096. It didn't change anything and the error persists.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 11):

Type `-Xmx1024m` instead of `-mx1024`.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. -mx works fine now. Please see below why it didn't work earlier.

Answer (score 7):

It should be -mx1024**m**. I skipped **m**.

One more thing: in the -cp, the model jar should also be included.

```
... -cp "stanford-parser.jar;stanford-parser-3.5.2-models.jar"...
```

(assuming you are using the latest version).

Otherwise an IO Exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some arguments that are preexisting in the IDE.
In eclipse:
Go to-> Run as-> run configuration-> Arguments
then Delete the arguments that are used previously.
Restart your eclipse.
Worked for me!